# JSerialComm Not Reading Whole String from Arduino

Tags: java, arduino

I am using jSerialComm with my Java application to receive data from an Arduino. However, the Java program is only reading incoming "bytes". This isn't good because my Arduino is printing a long string, and I want the Java app to read the whole string without losing any info. My Arduino sends the data string twice a second.

I am on Windows 10 with JDK 13, using IntelliJ, Adruino IDE 1.8.10.

Currently the String is very long with a potential for size changes, so I can't just read a certain number of bytes.

I am even currently printing the string with a # at the front and a * at the end. My design is currently losing data somehow though, only getting an acceptable string maybe 1 in 10 strings sent.

```
    byte[] newData = new byte[comPort.bytesAvailable(0];
    int numRead = comPort.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
    stringBuffer = new String(newData,0,numRead);
    if (stringBuffer.startsWith("#"))
    {
         serialString+=stringBuffer;
         while (!stringBuffer.endsWith("*")
         {
              numRead = comPort.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
              stringBuffer = new String(newData,0,numRead);
              serialString+=stringBuffer;
         }

         //double check it is the proper format
         if (serialString.startsWith("#") && serial.String.endsWith("*")
         {
              //do stuff
         }
         serialString = "";
    }
```

Is there a method besides readBytes() I can use?  I know I can use the getInputStream(), but I am uncertain where to go from there.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: allocate a buffer (`newData`) with fixed size. at the beginning there could be 0 bytes available

Comment: @Juraj Thank you for the response. I am looking up buffers, but I am unsure how they are used, especially in this instance. What kind of buffer do I need? BufferedInputStream? Thanks!

Comment: `byte[] newData = new byte[64];`

Comment: @Juraj I'm rather surprised, if I changed it to a hard-coded number, it never seemed to get the proper string.

Comment: print the stringBuffer to see what is received

Comment: @Juraj It looks just like mostly empty space being printed

Comment: I don't know what you send

Comment: @Juraj I print    #000,000,000,000,000,00.00,00.00,0,00,0000*      where each 0 could be any number, and could have any number of digits needed. There are 10 separate pieces of data all separated by commas.

Comment: but how do you print it? and the Java code is incomplete too.

Comment: @Juraj I left out the rest of the java code because I thought it was unneeded. The Arduino is literally printing that string using  Serial.println(allData); over 9600 baud

Answer (score 0):

Two issues come to mind.

1)  What is the synchronization method to only call your code when a complete message has been written?  What keeps the code from running when the Arduino has only written part of the message?

2)  Do you have any kind of flow control setup?  All the Arduino needs to do is write a long string but the PC side code needs to receive it into possibly multiple buffers.  If you are using a built-in hardware serial port then you can probably only receive 16 characters or so with a single PC interrupt.  Then that buffer gets sent by the OS to your application through the OS drivers.  If you are using a USB-to-Serial adapter then a similar issue may happen where the long string gets broken into multiple buffers that then get sent through the OS drivers to your program.  Your program doesn't need to know about all this "under the hood" buffer management but it can cause your PC to occasionally need the Arduino to pause sending data.  That's what a software handshake protocol is intended to do; allow a slow receiver to pause a fast sender.

Either of the above two issues could cause you to miss a character on occasion.  They are not the only sources of serial communication trouble but they are something that should be addressed by your system design.